# Adding a Betting option to Blackjack game

Tags: python

I am getting the error `TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not int` in the following code:

```py
class BJ_Player(BJ_Hand):
    """ A Blackjack Player. """
    def __init__(self, name, Pot):
        super(Pot, self).__init__(name)
        self.Pot=Pot
```

Can someone explain the error please? The code is quite long so its just a small snippet that I am struggling to understand.
I am trying to add an extra attribute to `BJ_Player` which will have a `Pot` of players betting money.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass `Pot` to `super`?

Comment: Please properly indent your code. Also what is the constructor of `BJ_Hand`?

Comment: There's not much to explain: the first argument to `super` must be a type. The `Pot` in `super(Pot, self)` must be a type, but it's actually an integer. `super` isn't meant for passing arguments to the class' constructor - you use `__init__` for this.

Comment: BTW, the usual way to use `super` in Python 3 is `super()` (with no arguments).

Comment: You could use `super(BJ_Player, self).__init__(name)` to call the superclass of **`BJ_Player`** (which would be `BJ_Hand` in this case). Generally speaking you wouldn't call it explicitly like that on some other class.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how `super` works. You should instead leave `super`s parenthesis empty, and pass in arguments via the `__init__` function

`super().__init__(Pot, name)`

Comment: If I do this , I get an error
"TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"
The reason I did it like this , because it work in the previous part of the code and also the book I am learning from showed an example like the way I did.

Here is a snippet of the bit that worked

class BJ_Hand(cards.Hand):
    """ A Blackjack Hand. """
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(BJ_Hand, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

full code here : https://pastebin.com/yTjtx1Sn
Thanks for looking into it